# Convergence in average on every set implies convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let's say we're working in a measure space $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$, and let $f_n, f$ be measurable. Suppose I have that, for any measurable set $E$,
$$
\int_E f_n d \mu \to \int_E f d \mu
$$
Does that imply that $f_n \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If each $f_n \ge 0$ and $\displaystyle \int_X f_n \, d\mu \to 0$, then $\displaystyle \int_E f_n \, d\mu \to 0$ for every measurable $E$. This doesn't imply that $f_n \to 0$ at any point, though.

For instance, let $X = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, take $\{f_n\}$ to be the indicators respectively of $[0,1/2]$, $[1/2,1]$, $[0,1/3]$, $[1/3,2/3]$, $[2/3,1]$, $[0,1/4]$, and so on.

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. I knew that counterexample from somewhere else too.